# For Booking.com, Selenium keeps deleting what I searched after clicking enter, even though it correctly does it before

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import translateXMLfile
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


    def setup_driver(self):
        
        opts = Options()  # Use webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        if self.HEADLESS:
            opts.add_argument('--headless')
            
        opts.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % self.WINDOW_SIZE)
        

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts)

        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get('https://www.booking.com')
        time.sleep(2)
        
      
    def select_dates(self):
        
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5)
        date = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="date-display-field-end"]')))
        date.click()

        next_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                               "button[class='a83ed08757 c21c56c305 f38b6daa18 d691166b09 f671049264 deab83296e f4552b6561 dc72a8413c f073249358']")
        next_button.click()

        inday = translateXMLfile.iday
        oday = translateXMLfile.oday

        formatted_inday = f"{inday:02d}"
        formatted_oday = f"{oday:02d}"

        date_element_xpath = f"//span[contains(@aria-label, '{formatted_inday} October 2023')]"
        date_element_xpatho = f"//span[contains(@aria-label, '{formatted_oday} October 2023')]"

        checkin_date = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, date_element_xpath)
        checkout_date = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, date_element_xpatho)

        checkin_date.click()
        checkout_date.click()
        
        search = self.driver.find_element(By.ID,':re:')
        search.send_keys(translateXMLfile.name)
        self.driver.save_screenshot('1st test.png')
        search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
       
        time.sleep(10)
        self.driver.save_screenshot('2nd test.png')
```

Here's before and after I'm trying to click enter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml9jZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOMkD.png)

I tried clicking the actual search button instead of enter, but that yields the same result. Any help would be really appreciated! I also tried waiting until clicking the search button, that doesn't work, as well as waiting until clicking enter after entering the search.

Comment: If you are able to provide the URL of the site, it would be helpful so that we can investigate further.

Comment: The URL is https://www.booking.com. I first enter the details I want to in the search bar as well as the dates, however, when I want to click enter, it deletes what I want to search, even though I just want to click enter.